# In two-dimensional even parity, how do we determine the corner parity bit?

Tags: encryption

In two-dimensional even parity, how do we determine the corner parity bit? 
Here's an example:

```
    1  0  0  1  y

    0  1  0  0  y

    0  1  0  1  y

    0  1  0  1  y

    x  x  x  x  z
```

Finding the parity bits where the x's and the y's is fine, But what about the parity bit in the lower right corner (z)? Do we look at the number of 1's in the corresponding column and/or in the corresponding row?

Comment: I suggest you have a read of [this help center page](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question). It may be that you can't delete this question because it has an answer...

Answer (score 1):

> Do we look at the number of 1's in the corresponding column and/or in the corresponding row?

Yes; you can do it in whichever direction is most convenient; it'll be the same either way.

In either direction, the parity of $z$ will be the parity of the entire data matrix (1 if there are an odd number of 1's, 0 if there are an even number).

Comment: Could you add a link or proof for the statement: "In either direction, the parity of z will be the parity of the entire data matrix"? (Or a short explanation perhaps, if the proof isn't too long)

Comment: @ÖmerEnesÖzmen: probably there are a number of simple proofs; here is one by induction; if we look at the all-0 matrix, then all the parity bits are 0, and hence the parity of $z$ will be 0, the parity of the entire data matrix.  And, if this is true for all matrices with $n-1$ bits set, it will also be true for all matrices with $n$ bits set (take an matrix with $n-1$ bits set, set a 0 bit to 1; that'll flip one row and one column parity bit, and hence the $z$ bit as well.  And, because we flipped one bit, we flipped the parity, hence it is true for $n$ (and hence by induction, for all $n$)

Comment: @ÖmerEnesÖzmen: there are certainly simpler proofs; however I am always amused by induction, and so that's what you get...